# Prove Abelian groups with two elements of order 2 have a subgroup of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, alternative-proof

Prove Abelian groups with two elements of order 2 have a subgroup of order 4.  (From *Gallian Algebra*).

My proof is below, as an answer.

1. Can you verify, critique, or improve my proof, or the proof writing; or provide an alternate or simpler proof?
2. I proved this "manually," via construction.  Is there a simpler, more direct, or more abstract approach?
3. My proof is limited to the exact question asked.  Is there a more universal approach that would work in similar questions as well?

Comment: I think that the attempted proof should be part of the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: What could be more simple or more direct, than to prove an existence statement by exhibiting (i.e., constructing) a witness? Other approaches will likely be complicated and indirect and should be avoided unless all else fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

More generally, if $G$ is an Abelian group with $H$ and $K$ subgroups thereof, the set
$$
HK=\{hk:h\in H,k\in K\}
$$
is a subgroup of $G$ (this holds also in general groups, provided one of the subgroups is normal).

In the case of Abelian groups, though, there is a further interesting property: the map
$$
\mu\colon H\times K\to HK,\qquad \mu(h,k)=hk
$$
is a group homomorphism (easy verification); the domain is the product group. What's the kernel? We have $\mu(h,k)=e$ if and only if $k=h^{-1}$, hence the kernel is
$$
\ker\mu=\{(x,x^{-1}):x\in H\cap K\}
$$
By the homomorphism theorem, we know that, in case of finite groups,
$$
|HK|=\frac{|H\times K|}{\lvert\ker\mu\rvert}=\dfrac{|H|\,|K|}{|H\cap K|}
$$
Note that $H\cap K$ is *not* $\ker\mu$, but they have the same order.

Now specialize this to $H=\langle a\rangle$ and $K=\langle b\rangle$, where $a,b\in G$ have order $2$ and $a\ne b$.

Then $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle=\{e\}$, because it cannot contain $a$ and is a subgroup of $\langle a\rangle$. Hence
$$
|\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle|=\frac{2\cdot2}{1}=4
$$
Since $e,a,b,ab\in\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle$, this is the full list of elements.

Can we generalize it? Yes, try the case of two elements of order the prime $p$; however, $a\ne b$ is no longer sufficient and something more has to be required, precisely that neither is a power of the other.

Comment: Or more generally can we put it like this? 'If $p$ is a prime and if an abelian group $G$ has $p$ elements of order $p$ (or at least $p$ elements of order $p$) then there exists a subgroup of order $p^2$ in $G$.

Comment: @YathirajSharma Yes, that’s even nicer. Such elements must lie in at least two distinct cyclic groups, which therefore have trivial intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be an Abelian group with elements $a,b$ such that $|a| = |b| = 2, a \neq b$.

The subgroup $H = {e, a, b, ab}$ is of order 4.  $ab \neq a$ or $b$, since neither $a$ or $b$ is the identity.  $ab \neq e$ since $aa = e, a \neq b$, and an element can have only one inverse.

$H$ includes all its inverses, as $(ab)^{-1} = ab$, since $abab=aabb=e$.

$H$ is closed, as $aba = aab = b$ and $bab = bba = b$.